# Error in connecting MS Excel VBA to AWS Cloud db using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, odbc

Couldn’t find much about connecting VBA to AWS Cloud on web.

Using this:

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};" & _
    "Server=IP-1234\DEV; authenticateduser = TRUE;database=DEV"
    conn.CommandTimeout = 30
    conn.Open
```

I do use SQL Server and it works fine on my system to query data in SQL Server for AWS Cloud.

I am getting this error: (SSL error)

[SSL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY4y1.png)

Comment: Your connection string is wrong.  {SQL Server} is a Driver not a Server.  And your error message clearly says that.  You may get an SSL error when you fix this, and may need to upgrade your ODBC driver. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thx for pointing out (that was typo). 
Updated my question for driver and error snapshot. Still a SSL Error

Comment: Did you try with the new ODBC driver?  What is your Windows version?

Comment: Windows 10 
I have tried SQL Server Native Client 11.0 (didn't work). The cloud db is AWS EC2.

Latest ODBC that's available is ODBC Driver for SQL Server 17.2.0.1 . Will get it installed and check..

Isn't there are different ODBC drivers for AWS ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-odbc-connection.html#obtain-odbc-url

Comment: AWS runs regular SQL Server.  But may force connection encryption which requires both certificate validation and cypher suite negotiation.  You can try to set the TrustServerCertificate connection string setting to turn the certificate verification off, but you might vulnerable to a MITM attack.

Comment: Of course AWS also has other databases (like redshift) and you can't use SQL Server drivers for those.

Comment: You're using a named instance in your connection string, `Server=IP-1234\DEV`. Do you have the SQL Browser service listening on udp/1434? Do you have Security Group(s) and Network ACL(s) allowing inbound access to udp/1434? You could avoid the complications of named instance resolution if you connect to the instance using its specific port, e.g.: if SQL Configuration Manager has it configured to listen on tcp/12345 then you only need tcp/12345 allowed for inbound access in Security Group(s) and Network ACL(s) and your connection string changes to `Server=IP-1234,12345; ...`